# How to return 1st record from group by

Tags: sql

Trying to return only the 1st supplier code and have all other fields unaffected.

```
`Select

Container.Part_Key,
Part.Part_No,
Part.Name,
Part.Revision,
Container.Quantity,
Container.Container_Status,
OP.Operation_No,
Opp.Operation_Code,
Part.Part_Status,
Supplier.Supplier_Code


From Part_v_Container as Container

Join Part_v_Part as Part
ON Part.Part_Key = Container.Part_Key


Join Part_v_Part_Operation as Op
On Op.Part_Operation_Key = Container.Part_Operation_Key

Join Part_v_Operation as OPP
On OPP.Operation_Key = OP.Operation_Key

Join part_v_approved_supplier as Approved
On Approved.part_key = container.part_key

Join common_v_Supplier as Supplier
On Supplier.supplier_no = Approved.Supplier_No


Where Container.Active = '1'

group by container.part_key`
```

There will be duplicate part numbers, revisions, etc. Not worried about that. I just want the part no to list only one approved supplier to the far right, even though for any given part, there are multiple approved suppliers listed in the database. 
Furthermore, the order the database lists the approved suppliers does not matter.

Thanks!

Comment: What dbms? MySQL, SQL Server, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a sub query in your select list

( select top 1 supplier.supplier_code 
From supplier
Where Supplier.supplier_no = Approved.Supplier_No order by Supplier.supplier_no) as supplier code

This can be the last field in the select list 
You could add An appropriate order by.

This would work in SQL Server